# asp.net how to put conditions on gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, conditional-statements

So I have connected a grid to a database where my database contains values of only 1, 2, and 3. I want to have it so that every box that has a 1 is green, 2 is yellow, and 3 is red.

My questions is where should i put the conditioning code and what language should i do it in?

The following information is just my gridview and the data i am linking it to.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Line" HeaderText="Line"  ItemStyle-Width="75" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-BackColor="#FF6699" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Jan" HeaderText="Jan"  ItemStyle-Width="75" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Feb" HeaderText="Feb"  ItemStyle-Width="75" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Mar" HeaderText="Mar"  ItemStyle-Width="75" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Apr" HeaderText="Apr"  ItemStyle-Width="75" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="May" HeaderText="May"  ItemStyle-Width="75" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Jun" HeaderText="Jun"  ItemStyle-Width="75" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Jul" HeaderText="Jul"  ItemStyle-Width="75" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Aug" HeaderText="Aug"  ItemStyle-Width="75" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Sep" HeaderText="Sep"  ItemStyle-Width="75" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Oct" HeaderText="Oct"  ItemStyle-Width="75" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nov" HeaderText="Nov"  ItemStyle-Width="75" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Dec" HeaderText="Dec"  ItemStyle-Width="75" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>



<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dashboardConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT 
        line AS Line, 
        [2012-01-31] AS 'Jan', 
        [2012-02-29] AS 'Feb', 
        [2012-03-31] AS 'Mar', 
        [2012-04-30] AS 'Apr', 
        [2012-05-31] AS 'May', 
        [2012-06-30] AS 'Jun', 
        [2012-07-31] AS 'Jul', 
        [2012-08-31] AS 'Aug', 
        [2012-09-30] AS 'Sep', 
        [2012-10-31] AS 'Oct', 
        [2012-11-30] AS 'Nov', 
        [2012-12-31] AS 'Dec'
    FROM
    (Select line, report_month, state FROM [Monthly_State]) AS sourcetable
    PIVOT
    (
    MAX(state) 
    FOR report_month IN ([2012-01-31], [2012-02-29], [2012-03-31], [2012-04-30], [2012-05-31], [2012-06-30], [2012-07-31], [2012-08-31], [2012-09-30], [2012-10-31], [2012-11-30], [2012-12-31])
    ) as pivottable; ">

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it by using template field and declare a public method in code behind as follows

`<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="cddasf" runat="server" CssClass='<%# GetClass(Eval("colum name")) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>`

In the code behind

```
public  string GetClass(object g)
{
```

//       process the value and return the css class name you want

```
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot use data binding expressions in CssClass property you must use code behind.
First you have to convert your columns to templates.
Instead of:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Jan" HeaderText="Jan"  ItemStyle-Width="75" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
```

Write:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Jan">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblJan" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("Jan") %>" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then you can use the RowDataBound to find your control with `e.Row.FindControl("lblJan")` and set the css class for it according to its value.

Answer (score 0):

In row data bound event of your grid view you have to place the conditions.

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
    // example 
    // You have to give the correct index ( starts from 0 ). Cell[0] will be the first column in your grid
       if(  e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "1" )
       {
           e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
       }
       if(  e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "2" )
       {
           e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
       }
       if(  e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "3" )
       {
           e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
       }
   // In the same way do for other columns

   }

 }
```

Comment: For some reason when I plug that in it doesn't work. According to the answer below I have to change how I make my grid is that true in order for the code above to work?

Comment: I don't know why this not works... I will check it. Below answer is also correct. For that you have to change all your bound columns to template field columns as mentioned by Amiram. and then you have to get the reference of each column as i mentioned but with a little change. like this `Label l1 = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("Label1");` in this way you will get the ref and then set it's background color.